# Issue with Tomcat new installation in to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I had Tomcat 8 installed on Eclipse and however I have removed that. Now I need it back. When I try to install tomcat 8 again, I get an issue.
I do not get a window to direct the path where I have Tomcat 8 downloaded. It just gives the window which prompts to add the projects.
But when I try to install another version of tomcat, everything is fine. I cannot work with other versions of tomcat since I have developed my projects using java 7.
Could someone help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

In your workbench open Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments. Remove Tomcat 8. Then add Tomcat 8 from here.